# Async call to a WebService method (Completed() methods not created)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1 to create a Metro App that consumes data from a Webservice (the webservice methods are not marked as Async).

I've seen a lot of examples over here using the Async() and Completed() methods but:

Once I add the service reference the service just contains the [MethodName]Async() methods but I can't find anywhere the [MethodName]Completed() methods.

```
ClientWebServiceSoapClient service = new ClientWebServiceSoapClient();
service.OpenAsync( );
Task<CallMethodResponse> methodTask = service.CallMethodAsync(new CallMethodRequest(new CallMethodRequestBody("paramA", "paramB", "")));
bool returnValue = methodTask.Result.Body.CallMethodResult;
service.CloseAsync();
```

This, obviously, does not work.

How can I get the result of the CallMethodAsync() if I don't have the possibility to put a Handler on the CallMethodCompleted()?

and also, Why I'm not having the Completed() methods?

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5 ? You can await the task and get `.Result`

Comment: Decorate the method you are using await in with the async keyword